# Install two apks of different versions of application

Tags: android, adb

I have two versions of the same Android application that I would like to have simultaneously on my Android device for easier testing. Is there a way to install both apk files such that they coexist on the same device?

Comment: just change the package name in your app in build.gradle. or create 2 flavors with a different package name.

Comment: Agree change package name of the newer version or just put applicationIdSuffix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [product flavours](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

```
productFlavors {
dev {
    applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
}
pro {
    applicationIdSuffix ".pro"
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
 }
}
```

**BUILDING APK**

Click on gradle on right side of android studio

app --> tasks --> build --> assemble

[image]

**OUTPUT**

generated at --> app --> build --> outputs --> apk

Answer (score 1):

Simple & Easy, just change the application id from **build.gradle**(app) and change the package name attribute from **manifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.netaq.schoolvoicedemo"
.
.
.
</manifest>
```

And to avoid duplicate permissions, make sure you don't have any signature permissions in your app manifest, for example:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

has to be renamed to:

```
<permission
        android:name="com.myappsecondversion.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.myappsecondversion.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Now you have a completely new application.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new user in your device and install another instance of the app in that user.

Or

You can download **Parallel Space** from play store and run multiple instance or installation of an application.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is a good solution but I was wondering if there is a way to have them in the same account/instance?

Comment: In android, package name should be unique to install it.
So, in ur case ur package name would be same so it can't be installed on same account.
The possible ways are :
1.Create a new account and install there.
2. Change the package name using apk tool.
3. Clone ur apk using Lucky Patcher or App cloner.

Comment: just change the android application id of the apps in gradle